# No Intellisense in MVC Areas with Kendo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, intellisense

We're having a strange issue with intellisense, Kendo and MVC Areas.

We have an MVC application that uses Areas and the Telerik Kendo controls.

One developer (Dev1) has NO problem with intellisense for the Kendo controls on pages that are contained within an Area.

Another developer (Dev2) only gets the Kendo intellisense on the pages in the root, but not on any pages contained within an Area.

Now, Dev2 has created a separate, vanilla application with Kendo and Areas and in this vanilla application, he has no problems working with intellisense on pages contained within an Area. Therefore, it doesn't seem that it's an environment issue, but rather something with the application. However, this does not explain why Dev1 is having not problems.

I have googled and read just about every article I can find on this and have tried numerous things. Surely I am missing something.

Any ideas?

We are both using VS2013, Framework 4.5.1.

I am on VS2013 update 1
The other developer is on VS2013 update 3

UPDATE (08/24/2014): ----------------------------------------

We have noticed that if we completely rebuild the application from scratch, intellisewe don't have the problem. This involves  coping over files/code and getting any used libraries from nuget.

Could it be possible that this is caused by a conflict with various libraries? Rebuilding the application from scratch is not a solution because we can't be having to do that everything this issue pops up. We really have to understand what disables intellisense within Areas and also for only certain developers.

Comment: Add the namespace in area/views/web.config and then reload the project.

Comment: HaBo, did that, no success. Also, I (Dev1) don't have the namespace in the Area's Web.Config and can still work with intellisense.

Comment: Did you try restarting your VS instance and rebuild you project again?

Comment: Restarted VS. When that didn't work, Rebooted. When that didn't work, thought about turning off the power in the building :).

Comment: Please see my update to the issue and let me know if this sheds any light on what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While working with Areas, every newly-added Area folder comes with their own web.config file in its View folder. It is necessary to add Kendo.UI assembly reference in all Area->AreaName->View->web.config. This will resolve Kendo UI intelligence issue in MVC-Area.